# form processing, integrating php within html

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I'm writing a simple form validation script, but one problem I've encountered is when I run my script via Google Chrome, my entire php tag shows up in the input boxes. In this case, my code for "firstname" will have `<?php echo $fn; ?>` in the input box. I tried to set my php variables, $fn, $ln, to null, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head> 
    <title> My Webpage! </title> 
</head>

<body>

<?php

include 'connect_inc.php';
include 'validate.php';

$fn = null;
$ln = null;
$age = null;
$birthday = null; 

    if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['birthday']))
    {
        $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
        $ln = $_POST['lastname'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];

        if(!empty($fn) && !empty($ln) && !empty($age) && !empty($birthday))
        {
            $sec = mysql_real_escape_string;
            $query = "INSERT INTO `ppl` VALUES('','".$sec($fn)."','".$sec($ln)."','".$sec($age)."','".$sec($birthday)."')";
            if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
            {
                header('Location: formSuccess.php');
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Unable to register at this time';
            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Please make sure that all the fields are filled';
        }
    }
?>

<form action = "form.php" method = "POST">
    Firstname: <br> <input type = "text" name = "firstname" maxlength = "40" value = "<?php echo $fn;?>" > <br><br>
    Lastname: <br> <input type = "text" name = "lastname" maxlength = "40"> <br><br>
    Age: <br> <input type = "text" name = "age" maxlength = "3"> <br><br>
    Birthday: <br><input type = "text" name = "birthday" maxlength = "13"> <br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: `my entire php tag shows up in the input boxes` that sounds like PHP isn't properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) { echo $fn; } ?>
```

The code above will verify if the form was submitted or not. If not, it will not echo $fn.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure, just a few suggestions.

1. Is your file named `*.html`? If yes, then can you rename it to something like `*.php` and add replace `<html>` tag with the following:

   `<?php ?>`

   `<html>`

and then try to run this file in browser (The *.php one)

Also, rather than setting all variables to `null`, you can try setting them to `""`.